# YouTube API v3: Can't process file

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When trying to upload mp4 video to YT using Data API I get success response (**200 OK**), but when I check it on YT video manager I see dummy thumbnail with the message: "Upload failed: Can't process file"

video url: http://media.gettyimages.com/videos/portrait-of-gloria-swanson-smoking-cigarette-lying-on-sofa-new-york-video-id95748490

YT API response:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#video",
 "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/4fCLHIOBuPZBsvDveLvdRGZ6dfk\"",
 "id": "OxctctEBrZk",
 "snippet": {
  "publishedAt": "2017-05-15T15:16:14.000Z",
  "channelId": "UCuHoiSfD2yC-4pKKq9aV0uA",
  "title": "UPLOAD video_title",
  "description": "yt_video_description",
  "thumbnails": {
   "default": {
    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/OxctctEBrZk/default.jpg",
    "width": 120,
    "height": 90
   },
   "medium": {
    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/OxctctEBrZk/mqdefault.jpg",
    "width": 320,
    "height": 180
   },
   "high": {
    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/OxctctEBrZk/hqdefault.jpg",
    "width": 480,
    "height": 360
   }
  },
  "channelTitle": "Test Social",
  "categoryId": "22",
  "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
  "localized": {
   "title": "UPLOAD video_title",
   "description": "yt_video_description"
  }
 },
 "contentDetails": {
  "duration": "PT0S",
  "dimension": "2d",
  "definition": "sd",
  "caption": "false",
  "licensedContent": false,
  "projection": "rectangular",
  "hasCustomThumbnail": false
 },
 "status": {
  "uploadStatus": "uploaded",
  "privacyStatus": "public",
  "license": "youtube",
  "embeddable": true,
  "publicStatsViewable": true
 }
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: this seems to have been opened [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/VX0xlTXYFCE), you can try to check it from time to time or "send a feedback" to youtube.